# why ConcurrentHashMap Segment array size is in power of two?

Tags: java

In Java Concurrent Hash Map, why segment array size has to be power of 2 (i.e.2^x >= concurrency level) , why not it is exact same as concurrency level ? is there any thing special in keeping things in power of two ? (I believe it has something to do with memory allocation.)

EDIT - comments found in ConcurrentHashMap class comment java 8

```
 /**
     * The maximum number of segments to allow; used to bound
     * constructor arguments. Must be power of two less than 1 << 24.
     */
    static final int MAX_SEGMENTS = 1 << 16; // slightly conservative
```

Comment: It would be useful to [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50620195/edit) and include where you found this info, as it's not mentioned in the [docs for the class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Comment: It's quite common to use powers of two for hash tables, just as it is to use prime numbers. Nothing unusual there. What makes you think it should be the same as the concurrency level?

Comment: Presumably it's because you can perform mod operations more efficiently on power of 2.